# Ignoring local URLs when using chrome.tabs.onUpdated

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that analyzes the websites a user visits. I've decided to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated to run my analysis script instead of content_scripts in manifest.json, because chrome.tabs.onUpdated does a better job picking up page refreshes on AJAX heavy sites.

I don't need to analyze updates to new, empty tabs or to chrome-extension:// (local) pages, and in fact an error will be thrown if I do try to inject a script into those tabs. Is there a more automatic way to ignore those pages, or do I have to do it the manual way with Try/Catch blocks or by analyzing the URL? I'm sure I can do it manually, but it seems there should be a more automatic way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore all local or internal chrome extension URLs by filtering out ones that start with `'chrome'`:

```
// Listen for changes on tabs
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    log_console('tab', tab)

    // If tab is not an internal chrome tab
    if (!tab.url.startsWith('chrome')) {
        console.log('Non-internal URL updated")
    }

});
```

Note that you need the `tabs` permission in your `manifest.json` if you want to access the URL, otherwise `tab.url` will be `undefined` and this won't work. If you can't get the `tabs` permission, your best bet might be to just catch and handle the error when you try to inject.